# How to solve this non-linear real equation system?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I would like to kindly ask:

does the non-linear equation system

> $(I)\ \ \ \ \ \cos(x_1)\cdot \cosh(y_1) = \cos(x_2)\cdot \cosh(y_2)$
>
> $(II)\ \ \ \sin(x_1)\cdot \sinh(y_1) = \sin(x_2)\cdot \sinh(y_2)$

have a non-trivial solution for $x_1,x_2 \in (0,\pi)$ and $y_1,y_2\in\mathbb{R}$?

The trivial solution is: $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$.

I tried to square both equations and use $\sin ^2 + \cos^2 = 1$, but it did not lead anywhere.

Comment: "*tried to square both equations*" $\;-\;$ That works, but isolate $\sin(x_2), \cos(x_2)$ first. Assuming $\,\sinh(y_2) \ne 0$, $\cosh(y_2)\ne 0\,$ you'll get an equation in the form $\,A\cos^2(x_1) + B\sin^2(x_1) = 1\,$ which you can solve for $\,x_1\,$.

Comment: Thank you very much.